# Determining the instantaneous axis of rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image]

Given the following image
The question states ,a heavy disc with radius R is rolling down hanging on two non-stretched strings wound around the disc very tightly.THe free ends of the strings are attached to a fixed support the strings are always tensed during the motion.At some instant,the angular velocity of the disc is w and angle between strings is a.Find velocity of centre of mass of disc at this moment.

I thought this may be solved by determining the IAOR, by intersecting the perpendiculars to the directions of velocities at the two points(points of contact with strings), but this gives me an incorrect answer.I realized i have been taking the directions of velocities incorrectly(i had taken them to be tangential to these points) but have since been unable to get the correct directions.Could anyone point out the correct directions of velocities(and why they are so) or provide another solution to this problem?

Comment: Remember the geometry of the centers [For Two Connected Bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation#Relative_centre_of_rotation_for_two_contacting_planar_bodies). You can consider each rope a body pivoting about it's support and in rolling contact with the disk.

Comment: sorry,but i still don't quite get it,if you are referring to sketch 4 of your link,then, in this case the instantaneous center should lie on a perpendicular through the point of contact. But this also passes through the center of the circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think this is going on here:

[image: pic]

The green rope rotates about *A*. The blue rope rotates about *B*. The disk rolls off the green rope and thus has a relative center of rotation at *D*. The disk also rolls off the blue rope and thus has a relative center of rotation at *E*.  The absolute center of rotation of the disk has to be on the line *AD* as well as on the line *BE* (per the [relative rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation#Relative_centre_of_rotation_for_two_contacting_planar_bodies)).

This happens at point *F* which is the unique instant center of rotation of the disk.

<sub>PS. The points *ADEB* create a [Four Bar Linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-bar_linkage)</sub>

Comment: i think i am getting it now.I didnt know this exact theorem ,rather, i only knew to determine iaor of a body we would have to find the points of intersection of perpendicular to the directions of velocites at any two points on the body.
But i think i get it now, thanks